# overlay over bootstrap panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel like following

```
 <div class="panel">
   <div class="panel-body">
     <div id="panel-overlay"></div>
     ...
   </div>
 </div>


#panel-overlay {
    /* set it to fill the whil screen */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* transparency for different browsers */
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 3000;
    /* hide it by default */
    display: none;
}

function panelOverlay() {
    var panel = $('.panel');
    var maskHeight = panel.height();
    var maskWidth = panel.width();
    $('#panel-overlay').css({
        height : maskHeight,
        width : maskWidth
    }).show();
}
```

how can i make the overlay appear over panel?

Comment: It needs some sort of positioning set to utilize the z-index. Have you tried setting it to `position: relative;`

Comment: yes i did but its not showing above..besides it's displacing down everything..

Comment: Give `position: relative` to the panel and a `position: absolute` to the overlay.

Comment: @HashemQolami perfect.if you can add as answer , i will accept that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create an overlay, the element should be removed from normal flow and get positioned relative to its parent.

Therefore, you could give `position: absolute;` declaration to the overlay element and `position: relative` to the panel (the container).

`relative` positioning is used here to establish a new [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details).

For instance:

```css
#panel-overlay {
    /* set it to fill the whole panel */
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.panel { position: relative; }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Huge help on a Monday morning.